# In android block a phone number without a single ring

Tags: java, android

I want to make an android app for blocking a phone number..
But the problem :=
If I block a number,it rings one time the then ends the call.
how can i made this without a single ring??

my code is like:--

```
public void blockCall(Context c, Bundle b)
    {
      TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) 
      c.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);  
      try {
       Class cls = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
       Method m = cls.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
       m.setAccessible(true);
       telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
       //telephonyService.silenceRinger();
       telephonyService.endCall();
      } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
        }
```

Comment: Even I worked on similar requirement, the reason is ,it takes a fraction of second to trigger your service. This is the wait time.Sometime I observed this time varies with device and OS as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your broadcast receiver, where you are listening for the incoming call add this method -

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
   try {
     Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
     Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
     m.setAccessible(true);
     telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
     String phoneNumber = bundle.getString("incoming_number");
     Log.d("INCOMING", phoneNumber);
     if ((phoneNumber != null)) { 
        telephonyService.endCall();
        Log.d("HANG UP", phoneNumber);
     }

   } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

This is working fine for me.

Comment: showing the error message in here :--
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
"intent cannot be resolved "

Comment: Code is blocking incoming calls..but still taking fraction of time before ending the call.